# Ascending and Desending order in same program using java

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

I want to sort the data according to id and marks pair.
ID should be in ascending order and marks should be in descending order, here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Student> al=new ArrayList<Student>();
    al.add(new Student(1,"dg",58));
    al.add(new Student(2,"dg",48));
    al.add(new Student(1,"dg",98));
    al.add(new Student(2,"dg",68));
    al.add(new Student(1,"dg",38));
    al.add(new Student(2,"dg",28));
    al.add(new Student(2,"dg",90));
```

**output like:**

```
1 dg 98  
1 dg 58  
1 dg 38  
2 dg 90  
2 dg 68  
2 dg 48  
2 dg 28
```

Comment: You can use [Collections.sort(List, Comparator>)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-). Implement the Comparator to your need.

Comment: @ AxelH i used but im sorted only id or marks but i want both

Comment: That's why you need to define your Comparator<Student> to compare both value correctly. Show us you actual comparison logic so that we can help you finish tt.

Comment: Collections.sort(al,(s1,s2)->{
return s1.id<s2.id?s1.marks>s2.marks?-1:s1.marks<s2.marks?1:0?s1.id>s2.id?1:0;
});  i got error

Comment: and i try this                               Collections.sort(al,(s1,s2)->{
   return s1.id>s2.id?s1.marks>s2.marks?-1:s1.marks<s2.marks?1:0:s1.id<s2.id?s1.marks>s2.marks?-1:s1.marks<s2.marks?1:0:s1.marks>s2.marks?-1:s1.marks<s2.marks?1:0;
  });                but it sort only marks

Comment: return s1.id<s2.id?-1:s1.id>s2.id?1:s1.marks>s2.marks?-1:0;    why here using -1,1,0 in this logic could anyone tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 Collections.sort(al,(s1,s2)->{

            return s1.id<s2.id?-1:s1.id>s2.id?1:s1.marks>s2.marks?-1:0;
        });
        al.forEach(p->{
            System.out.println(p);
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for the `Student` class or sort it directly using a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Comparator<Student> comparator = Comparator
    .comparing(Student::getId)                            // First ID in ascending order
    .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Student::getMark) // Then mark 
                             .reversed());                // ... but in descending order

al.sort(comparator);                                      // Here is the sort performed
```